# Trouble with MYSQL query BETWEEN two epoch timestamps?

Tags: php, mysql, unix-timestamp, epoch

I have epoch timestamps in my mysql database, I am using a Jquery datepicker to choose BETWEEN two dates. It works great when I choose at minimum between 1 day, but if I choose Sunday - Sunday ( the same day ) it should bring back records that have fallen on that day.

I am assuming it is because of the epoch timestamp integrated withing the datepicker.. When you choose a date, like today, it comes back with :

```
BETWEEN 1317103200 AND 1317103200 ....
```

I know how epoch timestamps work and it seems like it is to the second when you convert and do the math... How do I implement a DISTINT value for that FULL DAY -- so it just looks at the full 24 hours and not down to the millisecond???

```
SELECT category, id, date, title 
FROM myTable
WHERE date BETWEEN $beginDate AND $endDate AND...
```

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`mktime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) function where `$month`, `$day` and `$year` have been populated with the month, day and year from your date text box:

```
// Assumes date is in this format: dd/mm/yyyy, and your $_GET key is 'date'
list($day, $month, $year) = explode('/', $_GET['date']);

$beginDate = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
$endDate = mktime(23, 59, 59, $month, $day, $year);
```

Comment: And here I was trying to do it in MySQL. +1

Comment: How would I still use my GET variable with this??  isset($_GET

Comment: hmmmmm. still having issues... I think I need something like this: $beginDate = $_GET['beginDate'] : mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year); ... ???

Comment: Just change `$_GET['date']` to `$_GET['beginDate']` in the code above. If you're date format is dd/mm/yyyy then change the `list` statement to `list($month, $day, $year) = ...`

Comment: YES, and the same for $_GET['endDate'] .. AWESOME! Thanks!